# Proper way to define the date field of my typescript interface that will be loaded from my cloud function?

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Background: I'm using Vue and am interacting with cloud functions in order to retrieve data from firestore (I'm not querying the firestore directly). I'm calling a function where one of the fields returns the internal representation of firestore's timestamp (seconds, nanoseconds). Also, I'm totally new to typescript/Vue, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I defined a model class like such:

```
<script lang="ts">
interface Order {
  order_id: number
  uid: string
  create_date: Date //{ _seconds: number; _nanoseconds: number } ... from Firestore timestamp
}

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      userOrderInfo: [] as Order[],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getUserOrders() {
      userOrders({ uid: this.$store.state.uid })
        .then(result => {
          const orderList: Order[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data))
          const filteredOrders: Order[] = []
          orderList.forEach(o => {
              filteredOrders.push(o)
              const tempCreateDate = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(
                o.create_date._seconds,
                o.create_date._nanoseconds,
              o.create_date = tempCreateDate.toDate()
            }
          })
```

I'm having a problem with how I'm parsing and storing the create_date.

1. It seems ugly to me and I feel like there's probably a more elegant way to get it. It seems crude to have to get the nanoseconds and seconds and then recreate the Timestamp to call toDate().
2. VSCode is giving me this error, but everything seems to run fine.
   **"Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.Vetur(2339)"**
   It doesn't like how I defined _seconds and _nanoseconds in the data() definition.

Is there a better way to define my date and retrieve it?

3. o.create_date = tempCreateDate.toDate() is giving me this warning:
   **Identifier 'create_date' is not in camel case.eslint@typescript-eslint/camelcase**
   The problem is the cloud function is returning create_date in this format, so I can't make it camel case.

Is there any solution for this besides enduring this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just address the Typescript part because I haven't used Firebase and don't know how you could refactor the result of Firebase.

If your `create_date` has the following structure:

```js
{
  _seconds: number;
  _nanoseconds: number;
}
```

you can define that as an `interface`.

```js
<script lang="ts">
interface Order {
  order_id: number;
  uid: string;
  create_date: ResponseDate;
}
// please choose a more fitting name :)
interface ResponseDate {
  _seconds: number;
  _nanoseconds: number;
}
```

This should get rid of your VSCode TypeScript error because Typescript now properly understands what `create_date` is.

Now if you want to later update `o.create_date` to an actual `Date`, you need to add that to your interface-definition.

```js
<script lang="ts">
interface Order {
  order_id: number;
  uid: string;
  create_date: ResponseDate | Date; // Can be a ResponseDate or a Date
}
interface ResponseDate {
  _seconds: number;
  _nanoseconds: number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm now getting an error :
Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'DbDate | Date'.
  Property '_seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.Vetur(2339)

for this line

`o.create_date._seconds`

Comment: Ok I got something to work going with what you suggested. I had to also do this:

`(o.create_date as DbDate)._seconds, (o.create_date as DbDate)._nanoseconds,`

Would you suggest any other way? Or is this in line with your suggestion? Just wanted to make sure since I'm new to typescript. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is you access `o` in your forEach, but at this point it can be either a DbDate or a Date. So it's correct that TS throws you an error/warning because it's unclear at this point. The scenario is a little funky. Usually I'd create a new parameter to hold the date instead of overwriting the `create_date`. Then you also don't need to use `DbDate | Date` as your interface. If that's within your scope you can do that. I shall update my answer if that is an option for you.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. You mean to add another field to the interface, i.e. create_date_formatted? So this interface would have both create_date and create_date_formatted side by side? I think I'm open to that option if it's a cleaner design. Thanks!

Comment: Right, so later you say `o.create_date_formatted = tempCreateDate.toDate()` and you won't have any type issues. This is all when saying you cannot change the input from firestore. Maybe someone else has a better approach on how to change the data you get so you won't have to meddle with the different times at all :)

Comment: I appreciate your help and time. Thank you!